# How do I add a jar dependency in rosjava?

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a node written in ROSJava that depends on third party jar files.  How do I add these jar files so they can be found when I execute "gradlew installApp"?

I notice that by default numerous jar files are located in ~/.m2/repository/ros/rosjava_core/ and ~/.gradle/caches/artifacts-8/filestore/.  How do I add more jar files to either of these?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40538/how-do-i-add-a-jar-dependency-in-rosjava?/) by [liangfok](https://answers.ros.org/users/1811/liangfok/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2012-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The .m2 directory is where Maven downloads files to.

In Maven you add repos and dependencies to your pom files, in gradle to your gradle file.
As an example, in the rosjava stack build.gradle:

```
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  maven {
    url 'http://robotbrains.hideho.org/nexus/content/groups/ros-public'
  }
}
```

and in the rosjava PACKAGE's build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'org.apache.commons:com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging:1.1.1'
  compile 'org.apache.commons:com.springsource.org.apache.commons.net:2.0.0'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.8.2'
  }
```

Gradle then goes to the URL and tries to find the dependencies in the given version numbers, when gradle needs them.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-08-04**:
Additionally, you can install jar files directly to your local maven repository using something like (using junit as an example):
`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/PATH/TO/JAR/FILE.jar -DgroupId=junit -DartifactId=junit -Dversion=4.8.2 -Dpackaging=jar`

**Comment by [liangfok](https://answers.ros.org/users/1811/liangfok/) on 2012-08-06**:
Thank you, it worked.  After manually adding the jar files, I had to add the following to my package's build.gradle's dependency list: compile '[groupId]:[artifactId]:[version]'

**Comment by [liangfok](https://answers.ros.org/users/1811/liangfok/) on 2012-08-06**:
The jar file I needed to add was JFreeChart's (http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/).  I manually installed it in my local maven repository using the command above and it worked, but I wonder if there's some on-line maven repository that I could have used to automatically install it.

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2012-11-03**:
Hi, I have the same issue! I have a jar file containing some java classes. I want to use them in my java program. Shall I manually add it ~/.gradle/caches/artifacts-8/filestore/? but I see three dirs jar,pom and source. Do I make it by mkdir command and what to add in there? Thanks in advance